# How to encode an HTTP GET request

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Ok so I have the following code that I'm currently going to use for a get response. I know that I need to encode that response as well as set it to a new NSString variable(because I'd like to use the response for logic), how might I do this?

```
NSLog(@"textField *UserEmail did end editing");

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"*will have url here*"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSError *requestError;
NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];

NSLog(response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Cheers:)